# Stripe Subscription Adjustment based upon usage of second product

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

Here is an example of what is going on and what I need to do.

Lawyer pays for legal services monthly website for $39.  A second product of the website is to monitor legal cases (like a divorce so the lawyer knows what is filed).  Each monitored case is $4.99 but the first 5 cases are free as part of the $39 subscription.  The lawyer can use the $4.99 as a client expense with a receipt specific to that client.  Creating a separate subscription specific to each client name is easy and does the proration when started in the middle of the billing cycle. But when I start a subscription for the first 5 cases, that's an additional $24.95 (4.99 x 5).  The total should still be $39, not $39 plus $24.95.

I tried coupons, but that didn't prorate the base $39 for the time left.  Is there a way to apply the coupon back to the beginning of the month?

My other thought was to adjust the price of the underlying subscription for $39.00 and make the new one $34.01, then take off another $4.99 when 2 cases are monitored and finally on the 6th case, that's beyond the amount included so the 6th case would be charged $4.99 and so on for any additional cases.

What would be the best way to structure this pricing model in Stripe?

Comment: Can you clarify if I'm understanding your pricing model correctly? If you had a lawyer with 6 cases, you'd want the following: One Subscription for $39 (the normal monthly fees), Five separate Subscriptions for $0 (the five free cases they get), One Subscription for $4.99 (the sixth case that isn't free). There are ways to model this, but is having a separate subscription for each client a hard requirement? I feel like this will be hard for you manage in the long run (like what if in the above scenario one of the free cases finishes - do you need to update the 6th case to now be free?)

Comment: Karbi - you are correct. It would be easy if it were a pure volume pricing model.  The difference is that I need to give individual receipts for each of the cases because the law firm can then pass that on to the client as an expense. But in order to pass it on as an expense, they must have a specific receipt with that client's name on it. I believe using the Stripe receipt function is going to be the easiest.